# GET/ADD Events to google calendar with a service account

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have to access a google calendar from a java webapplication to get and especially add events to a shared google calendar
I followed the java quickstart [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) from google and everything works fine so far

then I changed the authorize method in that example to use a service account and the authentication seems to work but the calendar List returned from google is empty

I already shared the calendar with the service account email but that doesnt change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service account is a dummy user. It has its own Google Calendar account.  By default it doesn't have access to any Google Calendars you need to either share a google calendar with it or insert a new Google Calendars into it.

Calendar.list is something else entirely its basically the little box at the bottom left in the Calendars website.   In order for a calendar to appear there it I needs to be inserted into the calendar.list.

**Solution:**

Go to the Google calendar website add the service account email address as a user of your calendar.  Then the service account will be able to access it.  If you want you can programmatically insert it into calendar.list if you really need it to be there.   IMO there is really not much point for Calendar.list with a service account.

**update**

You should be able to grant your service account access to do what ever you like like any other user.

[image]

If you want it in [calendar.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) call [Calendarlist.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) from the service account code.  You will only need to run it once to insert the calendar in question into the service accounts calendar list.

try running [Calendars.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) on the calendar it should have access without needing to insert it into calendar.list

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only use the calendar.list at the moment as a test if the service account "user" has acces to something from my calendars. I already added the service account to my calendar but i still cant see any events. Another problem is that I can only give it the rights to see free/busy the options to see all the event details or to make changes to events are disabled

Comment: I did add the service account to the calendar but the only Permission Setting I can choose is "See only free/busy (hide details)  and even with that setting it wont show upcomming events in that calendar

Comment: are you the owner of the calendar you should have access to all the settings.

Comment: yes I am the owner of that calendar  it is a google business account or however it is called but even the admin of the company can only add the service account with this option to one of his calendars